# Visual Studio duplicating resource .cs file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resource-files

Visual Studio has begun exhibiting a rather irritating quirk. When I edit a resource file (using either the designer view or editing the XML directly), it creates a duplicate resource Designer.cs file, which causes the project to be unable to build.

Example: Let's say my resource file is called ProjectSQL.resx. If you expand ProjectSQL.resx in the Solution Explorer, it shows ProjectSQL.Designer.cs. When I make an edit to one of the queries defined in ProjectSQL.resx, it saves fine, but creates another file called ProjectSQL1.Designer.cs.

In that example, there's now two class files with the same class name, causing the build failure.

Has anyone had this problem before? How did you fix it? I've tried closing the solution and reopening, as well as restarting Visual Studio. Using VS 2010 Premium on Windows 7 Ultimate for those interested.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532800/msdatasetgenerator-create-another-designer1-cs-file-for-my-typed-dataset

Comment: The tag described on that page was it. Somehow VS decided to put that 1 in there. Thanks so much! If you put together an answer describing the LastGenOutput tag in the project file, I'll be happy to accept it and get you some credit for helping me.

Comment: I have no idea what causes this value to change, it is just a workaround.  Please feel free to post the answer and accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant the link is dead.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140610215024/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532800/msdatasetgenerator-create-another-designer1-cs-file-for-my-typed-dataset

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In case this happens to anyone else and you find yourself here, Hans' comment above pointed me toward the project file. I had to close the solution, find the `LastGenOutput` tag in the project XML file, and change the name of the resource output back to ProjectSQL from ProjectSQL1.

I still have no idea how this happened. But at least it's fixed now.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It worked. And BTW, to edit project files, you can just unload the project, right click the project and select "Edit project file" without closing the solution. Just discovered this ( in VS 2015 ) so I wanted to share.

Comment: Why does this even happen?

Comment: Credit to Felipe for planting the seed and to @iandisme for validation

Answer (score 12):

Replace in .csproj file the code like below:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\ProjectSQL.resx">
   <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
   <LastGenOutput>ProjectSQL1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

With code like below:-

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\ProjectSQL.resx">    
   <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
   <LastGenOutput>ProjectSQL.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/227676/Resource-file-regenerating

Comment: Everytime I have to change de .csproj I feel like It's a workaround. It worked to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the "**Custom Tool**" entry. appropriate rpt file it's located right click on rpt file --> properties ---> custom tool ---> clear